# Error while calling turtle window again after closing it through a button in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-turtle

The following code is of tkinter window containing a button to call a turtle window

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from turtlefunc import *
root = Tk()

#creating a button
myButton = Button(root, text="call turtle",command =call)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The following code is of the turtle window

```
import turtle
def call():
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.bgcolor('white')
    t.width(3)
    for i in range(1,5):
        t.forward(20)
        t.left(90)
    t.hideturtle()
    turtle.exitonclick()
```

The button works fine the first time but returns an error while calling the turtle window or function the second time

error:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\PycharmProjects\GAME ARCADE GUI\turtlefunc.py", line 3, in call
    t = turtle.Turtle()
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
    RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
    self._update_data()
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()
  File "C:\Users\sharmila\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

Comment: try destroying that instance of Turtle maybe, tho I think this has been asked before

Comment: @Matiiss If you can help me with that too, it would be really helpful . I'm unable to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have to `.clear()` your canvas before you destroy it, so all the turtles are out of the equation.  That way, it doesn't raise `Terminator` when when it no longer sees `TurtleScreen._RUNNING`

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
import turtle as trt

title = 'Python Turtle'
root  = tk .Tk() ; root .title( title )

Width, Height  = 500, 500
myButton = None  ##  empty, forward declaration

def call():
    myButton .pack_forget()  ##  hide button
    canvas  = tk .Canvas( root, width=Width, height=Height )
    canvas .pack()  ##  show canvas
    turtle  = trt .RawTurtle( canvas=canvas )
    screen  = turtle .getscreen()
    screen .bgcolor('white')
    turtle .width( 3 )
    for i in range( 1, 5 ):
        turtle .forward( 20 )
        turtle .left( 90 )
    turtle .hideturtle()
    def dest( x, y ):
        screen .clear()  ##  destroy turtles
        canvas .destroy()
        myButton .pack()  ##  show button again
    screen .onclick( dest )

##  creating a button
myButton = tk .Button( root,  text='call turtle',  width=len(title) +10,  command=call )
myButton .pack()

root .mainloop()
```

You don't really need to 'destroy' the canvas and rebuild it each time, though.  You can just 'hide' it when it's not being used.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import tkinter as tk
import turtle as trt

title = 'Python Turtle'
root  = tk .Tk() ; root .title( title )

Width, Height  = 500, 500
canvas  = tk .Canvas( root, width=Width, height=Height )
myButton = None  ##  empty, forward declaration

def call():
    myButton .pack_forget()  ##  hide button
    canvas .pack()  ##  show canvas
    turtle  = trt .RawTurtle( canvas=canvas )
    screen  = turtle .getscreen()
    screen .bgcolor('white')
    turtle .width( 3 )
    for i in range( 1, 5 ):
        turtle .forward( 20 )
        turtle .left( 90 )
    turtle .hideturtle()
    def dest( x, y ):
        screen .clear()  ##  destroy turtles
        canvas .pack_forget()  ##  hide canvas, so you can reuse it later
        myButton .pack()  ##  show button again
    screen .onclick( dest )

##  creating a button
myButton = tk .Button( root,  text='call turtle',  width=len(title) +10,  command=call )
myButton .pack()

root .mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The module uses a class variable _RUNNING which remains true between executions when running like this. I have requested for the module to be updated through a pull request.

Meanwhile, work around/working example

1)

```
import importlib
import turtle
def call():
    importlib.reload(turtle)
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    screen.bgcolor('white')
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.width(3)
    for i in range(1,5):
        t.forward(20)
        t.left(90)
    t.hideturtle()
    turtle.exitonclick()
```

2. 

```
import turtle
def call():
    screen = turtle.Screen()
    turtle.TurtleScreen._RUNNING=True
    screen.bgcolor('white')
    t = turtle.Turtle()
    t.width(3)
    for i in range(1,5):
        t.forward(20)
        t.left(90)
    t.hideturtle()
    turtle.exitonclick()
```